# AWS Lambda error No module named 'StringIO' or No module named 'StringIO'

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-ses

I try to use AWS Lambda for mass email sending, the code we use as the link below:
https://aws.amazon.com/cn/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mass-email-ses-lambda/

```
from __future__ import print_function

import StringIO
import csv
import json
import os
import urllib
import zlib

from time import strftime, gmtime
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

import boto3
import botocore
import concurrent.futures

__author__ = 'Said Ali Samed'
__date__ = '10/04/2016'
__version__ = '1.0'

# Get Lambda environment variables
region = os.environ['us-east-1']
max_threads = os.environ['10']
text_message_file = os.environ['email_body.txt']
html_message_file = os.environ['email_body.html']

# Initialize clients
s3 = boto3.client('s3', region_name=region)
ses = boto3.client('ses', region_name=region)
send_errors = []
mime_message_text = ''
mime_message_html = ''


def current_time():
    return strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S UTC", gmtime())


def mime_email(subject, from_address, to_address, text_message=None, html_message=None):
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = from_address
    msg['To'] = to_address
    if text_message:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(text_message, 'plain'))
    if html_message:
        msg.attach(MIMEText(html_message, 'html'))

    return msg.as_string()


def send_mail(from_address, to_address, message):
    global send_errors
    try:
        response = ses.send_raw_email(
            Source=from_address,
            Destinations=[
                to_address,
            ],
            RawMessage={
                'Data': message
            }
        )
        if not isinstance(response, dict):  # log failed requests only
            send_errors.append('%s, %s, %s' % (current_time(), to_address, response))
    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        send_errors.append('%s, %s, %s, %s' %
                           (current_time(),
                               to_address,
                               ', '.join("%s=%r" % (k, v) for (k, v) in e.response['ResponseMetadata'].iteritems()),
                               e.message))


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    global send_errors
    global mime_message_text
    global mime_message_html
    try:
        # Read the uploaded csv file from the bucket into python dictionary list
        bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
        key = urllib.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']).decode('utf8')
        response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        body = zlib.decompress(response['Body'].read(), 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
        reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(body),
                                fieldnames=['from_address', 'to_address', 'subject', 'message'])

        # Read the message files
        try:
            response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=text_message_file)
            mime_message_text = response['Body'].read()
        except:
            mime_message_text = None
            print('Failed to read text message file. Did you upload %s?' % text_message_file)
        try:
            response = s3.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=html_message_file)
            mime_message_html = response['Body'].read()
        except:
            mime_message_html = None
            print('Failed to read html message file. Did you upload %s?' % html_message_file)

        if not mime_message_text and not mime_message_html:
            raise ValueError('Cannot continue without a text or html message file.')

        # Send in parallel using several threads
        e = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_threads)
        for row in reader:
            from_address = row['from_address'].strip()
            to_address = row['to_address'].strip()
            subject = row['subject'].strip()
            message = mime_email(subject, from_address, to_address, mime_message_text, mime_message_html)
            e.submit(send_mail, from_address, to_address, message)
        e.shutdown()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e.message + ' Aborting...')
        raise e

    print('Send email complete.')

    # Remove the uploaded csv file
    try:
        response = s3.delete_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        if 'ResponseMetadata' in response.keys() and response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 204:
            print('Removed s3://%s/%s' % (bucket, key))
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)

    # Upload errors if any to S3
    if len(send_errors) > 0:
        try:
            result_data = '\n'.join(send_errors)
            logfile_key = key.replace('.csv.gz', '') + '_error.log'
            response = s3.put_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=logfile_key, Body=result_data)
            if 'ResponseMetadata' in response.keys() and response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
                print('Send email errors saved in s3://%s/%s' % (bucket, logfile_key))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            raise e
        # Reset publish error log
        send_errors = []


if __name__ == "__main__":
    json_content = json.loads(open('event.json', 'r').read())
    lambda_handler(json_content, None)
```

but it has problem when i choose python 2.7.the error is

```
module initialization error 'us-east-1'
```

when i choose python 3.6 the error is

```
Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module named 'StringIO'
```

anyone can tell me what is the problem it is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please set the environment variables as described in [step 4 of the article](https://aws.amazon.com/cn/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/mass-email-ses-lambda/): 
"*Configure Lambda environment variables appropriate to your usage scenario. For example, the following variables would be valid for a given use case:
REGION=us-east-1, MAX_THREADS=10, TEXT_MESSAGE_FILE=email_body.txt, HTML_MESSAGE_FILE=email_body.html.*"

What was done (as per the code provided in the question) is replacing names of  environment variables with their values, which means that python is looking for e.g. `'us-east-1'` environment variable which isn't there...

This is the original code

```
# Get Lambda environment variables
region = os.environ['REGION']
max_threads = os.environ['MAX_THREADS']
text_message_file = os.environ['TEXT_MESSAGE_FILE']
html_message_file = os.environ['HTML_MESSAGE_FILE']
```

You can also hard-code the values, like below:

```
# Get Lambda environment variables
region = 'us-east-1'
max_threads = '10'
text_message_file = 'email_body.txt'
html_message_file = 'email_body.html'
```

but I'd suggest to set the environment variables instead (and use the version of script provided by the [article author](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-support-tools/blob/master/SES/SESMailer/ses_mailer.py)). When it comes to setting environment variables in Lambda, [see this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/env_variables.html) :)

Comment: Note that AWS Lambda automatically provides an AWS_REGION environment variable for your use, so there's no need to manually create a REGION environment variable.

Answer (score 3):

From Python v3, the [StringIO module has gone](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html). Instead, import the io module and use io.StringIO.

The problem with the v27 version is presumably that the following  statement is failing:

```
region = os.environ['us-east-1']
```

This will result in a KeyError if `us-east-1` is not an available environment variable. Instead use `AWS_REGION` or `AWS_DEFAULT_REGION`. See the full list of [Lambda environment variables](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-envvars.html#configuration-envvars-runtime).